# how to send and receive hex using socket in php?

Tags: php, sockets, hex

I have the following code:

```
$send1 = 0x01;
$send2 = 0x03;
$send3 = 0x00;
$send4 = 0x00;
```

and I send it like this:

```
socket_write($spawn, $send1, strlen ($send1)) or die("Could not write output\n");
socket_write($spawn, $send2, strlen ($send2)) or die("Could not write output\n");
socket_write($spawn, $send3, strlen ($send3)) or die("Could not write output\n");
socket_write($spawn, $send4, strlen ($send4)) or die("Could not write output\n");
```

the receiving side get it like this:

```
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
    echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
```

and the data received is: `1300`, how to send and receive hex using socket in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does not have a built in hex datatype so when you do this:

```
$send1 = 0x01;
```

this is treated as integer by php. (Try var_dump(0x01) and you will get int(1))
So you can either send the data as a string and process it on the receiving side like so:

```
$send1 = "0x01";
$send1 = "0x02";
$send1 = "0x03";
$send1 = "0x04";
```

or you can send the integer values over socket and then convert them into hex values for processing at the receiving end:

```
$send1 = 1;
$send2 = 2;
$send3 = 3;
$send4 = 4;
```

At the receiving end:

```
var_dump(dec2hex($result));
```

(processing one input at a time so that you can separate them).

Comment: but what about the $send2 = "0xCD", how to receive it and convert it to hex?

Comment: on 2nd thought, I realized that the code is sending the values in hexadecimal to begin with. So var_dump(0x01) gives int(1)
and var_dump(0xcd) gives int(205). You might want to try sending something like this: $send1 = 0xcd; (only a single value) and see what you get at the receiving end. If you are indeed getting a hex value at the receiving end, then all you need to do is add a separator after each hex value(like | for e.g., ) and then split the hex input at the receiving end on that separator for further processing. I hope this all makes sense.